# Why doesn't this code produce the correct output?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Given a string and a number, this function will produce all possible combinations of n letters from that string.

i.e. If I pass "abcd" and 3, then I should get the following output:

```
abc
abd
acd
bcd
```

This is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self expand_combinations:@"abcd" arg2:@"" arg3:3];
}

-(void) expand_combinations: (NSString *) remaining_string arg2:(NSString *)s arg3:(int) remain_depth
{
    if(remain_depth==0)
    {
        printf("%s\n",[s UTF8String]);
        return;
    }

    for(int k=0; k < [remaining_string length]; ++k)
    {
        s = [s stringByAppendingString:[[remaining_string substringFromIndex:k] substringToIndex:1]];
        [self expand_combinations:[remaining_string substringFromIndex:k+1] arg2:s arg3:remain_depth - 1];
    }
    return;
}
```

Instead this is what it prints out

```
abc
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

Comment: What's the original remaining_string? abc?

Comment: Yes, it is passed to the function in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @awake I can't believe your last dozen questions or so were all asked to come up with a permutation function in Objective-C.

Comment: It's not a permutation function, it's a combination function.

Comment: @NullUserException hehe, thought the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick and dirty solution (didn't rename variable names and so on) for your function

```
-(void) expand_combinations: (NSString *) remaining_string arg2:(NSString *)s arg3:(int) remain_depth
{
    NSString *newString = [remaining_string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(remain_depth, 1) withString:@""];
    // NSLog(newString);

    if(remain_depth==0)
    {
        printf("%s\n",[s UTF8String]);
        return;
    }
    [self expand_combinations:remaining_string arg2:s arg3:remain_depth - 1];
    return;
}
```

Output (I used NSLog)

```
2010-09-26 04:27:26.462 Untitled[5417:207] abc
2010-09-26 04:27:26.462 Untitled[5417:207] abd
2010-09-26 04:27:26.463 Untitled[5417:207] acd
2010-09-26 04:27:26.467 Untitled[5417:207] bcd
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this. It doesn't print anything. Where did you put the log statement?

Comment: @awake, there's nothing wrong, please look at the code (and its comments) again.

Comment: I copy and pasted the code. It doesn't work.

Comment: @awake, did you look at the comment in the code, like I wrote?

Comment: Just uncomment the NSLog to see the new string in your Console. I commented it out.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. Here it is.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self expand_combinations:@"abcd" arg2:@"" arg3:3];
}

-(void) expand_combinations: (NSString *) remaining_string arg2:(NSString *)s arg3:(int) remain_depth
{
    if(remain_depth==0)
    {
        printf("%s\n",[s UTF8String]);
        return;
    }

    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:s];
    for(int k=0; k < [remaining_string length]; ++k)
    {

        str = [s stringByAppendingString:[[remaining_string substringFromIndex:k] substringToIndex:1]];
        [self expand_combinations:[remaining_string substringFromIndex:k+1] arg2:str arg3:remain_depth - 1];

    }
    return;
}
```

The changes I made to make it work are in the line

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:s];
```

From there I replace every instance of s with str. It seems that by using s instead of str, some important value was getting overwritten which was causing the problem to not work correctly. It is necessary to create another NSString variable str so that the contents of s do not get overwritten.

Comment: Not quite useful as you do not explain what are the changes with the code in your question. Please note this is a Q&A site, for ALL of us to learn from, not a help forum.

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer, so remove the -1 vote. :)

Comment: awakeFromNib: This version leaks the string you created in that initializer, by replacing it with the string you obtained from your first `stringByAppendingString:` message. There is no reason to create that first string object at all. Also, you should read up on `substringWithRange:`.