# When not to alloc and init an NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring, string

Whenever I need to create a new NSString variable I always alloc and init it. It seems that there are times when you don't want to do this. How do you know when to alloc and init an NSString and when not to?

Comment: Your question makes little sense. Show us some examples.

Comment: Creating a new `NSString` via `[[NSString alloc] init];` is one of the most pointless things you could do in Cocoa.  The resulting string is immutable and empty.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Whenever I need to create a new NSString variable I always alloc and init it.

No, that doesn't make sense.

The *variable* exists from the moment the program encounters the point where you declare it:

```
NSString *myString;
```

This variable is not an NSString. It is storage for a pointer to an NSString. That's what the `*` indicates: That this variable holds a pointer.

The NSString *object* exists only from the moment you create one:

```
[[NSString alloc] init];
```

and the pointer to that object is only in the variable from the moment you assign it there:

```
myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
//Or, initializing the variable in its declaration:
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Thus, if you're going to get a string object from somewhere else (e.g., `substringWithRange:`), you can skip creating a new, empty one, because you're just going to replace the pointer to the empty string with the pointer to the other one.

Sometimes you do want to create an empty string; for example, if you're going to obtain a bunch of strings one at a time (e.g., from an NSScanner) and want to concatenate some or all of them into one big string, you can create an empty mutable string (using `alloc` and `init`) and send it `appendString:` messages to do the concatenations.

You also need to `release` any object you create by `alloc`. This is one of the rules in the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).

Comment: Reminder: Ignore the part about `release` when building your app under [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting). Also, if you want to self-document instantiating an empty string (as opposed to the nil pointer described in this answer), use this convenience class method: `NSString* myString = [NSString string];`

Comment: @BasilBourque: Even more idiomatic would be `@""`, although that isn't guaranteed to be a new string (though neither is `[[NSString alloc] init]`, which may return a constant string).

Comment: `[NSString string]` seems more self-documenting to me as this absolutely means "I want a non-nil empty string". `@""` has some ambiguity – did the author merely forget to fill in the intended string literal? (I've seen that happen when indecision hovered over the choice of exact wording.) On the other hand, if indeed you may possibly change this in the future to be non-empty with some kind of text, then use `@""` in the first place.

Comment: So you use alloc init 'if' you don't want to say `mystring = youstring` i.e. you want to give a new value like @"Thanks_Peter" OR that if you wanted to append something to it, but since you can't append to something that isn't created yet, you will create an empty one?--Is that correct?

Comment: @Honey: I'm not sure what you meant by the former. The latter is only correct for NSMutableString: You can't append to `[[NSString alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to initialise it to a known value, there is little point in using `alloc`, you can just use a string literal:

```
NSString* myStr = @"Some value";
```

If you want to initialise it with a format or whatever, but don't need it to stick around beyond the current autorelease pool lifetime, it's a bit neater to use the class convenience methods:

```
NSString* myTempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIntVar];
```

If you need its lifetime to go beyond that, either `alloc`/`init` or else add a `retain` to the previous call. I tend to slightly prefer the latter, but the two are pretty much equivalent. Either way you will need a balancing `release` later.

Note that, since `NSString` is not mutable, this sort of thing is not only unnecessary but actively **wrong**:

```
// don't do this!
NSString* myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
myStr = someOtherStr;
```

since it leaks the initial placeholder value.

Comment: How do you know what the current autorelease pool lifetime is?

Comment: @awakeFromNib By reading the [relevant section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) of the memory management docs. Commonly you can think of an autoreleased object as lasting until you let it out of your sight, and then just a teensy bit longer (ie, long enough to be a valid return value). If you are creating stuff in a loop you may want to manage an autorelease pool of your own to avoid building up a huge pile of unreleased allocations, but the default should be fine for a handful of strings during event handling.

Comment: This is nit-picky, but the @"" placeholder value doesn't get leaked: it takes up space in the app binary, so there's nothing to free. It's kind of wasteful, but you're not actually leaking memory...

Comment: @KevinFrei By placeholder I mean the explicitly `alloc`-ed object assigned to `myStr`, not the static `@""` passed to `initWithString:`. The pointer is lost when `someOtherStr` is assigned, so -- at least *conceptually* -- it leaks. It's possible that `initWithString:` internally deallocs the alloced string and returns instead a pointer to the constant `@""`, but that isn't documented and would have to be considered an implementation detail. Consider the situation if instead of `initWithString:` I'd used an `initWithFormat:` or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that there are times when you don't want to do this.

I can't think of any time when I *would* want to alloc/init a NSString.  Since NSStringgs are immutable, you pretty much always create new strings by one of:

- convenience class method e.g.

  ```
  NSString* foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:...];
  ```
- literal

  ```
  NSString* foo = @"literal";
  ```
- NSString instance method

  ```
  NSString* foo = [bar uppercaseString];
  ```
- copy from mutable string

  ```
  NSString* foo = [mutableBar copy];  // foo needs to be released or autoreleased in this case
  ```

Comment: You might want to read a file and stash it in an instance variable, in which case you'd use `initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`. (Or `stringWith…` and `retain`, but that's no more efficient for you or the program.)

Comment: @Peter Hosey: I'd use the convenience class method in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are referring to using StringWithString or similar instead of initWithString?  StringWithString alloc and inits for you under the hood and then returns an autoreleased string.

If you don't need to do any string manipulation other than to have the string, you can use `NSString *str = @"string";`

In general with iOS, the tighter you manage your memory the better.  This means that if you don't need to return a string from a method, you should alloc init and then release it.

If you need to return a string, of course you'll need to return an autoreleased string. I don't think its any more complicated than that.

Comment: Nope. He's referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796312/why-doesnt-this-code-produce-the-correct-output/3796955#3796955