# NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString fails

Tags: ios, string, replace

I'm trying to replace a string with another one by using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString, but for some reason it's giving me this error:

> -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e49ef0
>   2012-05-14 16:30:49.741 coop[78129:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e49ef0'

```
NSString *_currentGroup;
NSString *location = [current objectForKey:@"location"];
if(_currentGroup != nil) 
{
    NSLog(@"_currentGroup: %@", _currentGroup);
    // OUTPUT: _currentGroup: 92

    location = [location stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%group_id%" withString:_currentGroup];
}
```

When I try the following it just works

> location = [location stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%group_id%" withString:@"anyOtherString"];

Am I still missing something?

Comment: does NSLog(@"_currentGroup: %@", _currentGroup);
    actually give  OUTPUT: _currentGroup: 92

Comment: Jup, that's the output I get from it.

Comment: you do not initialize _currentGroup

Comment: Do I even neet to initialize it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801156/when-not-to-alloc-and-init-an-nsstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "NSString" is actually an `NSNumber`. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: Ah, turns out the result I got back from my datafeed was an int, converting it into a string solved this.