# Objective-C: Trouble returning an NSString in my method

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am new to Objective-C and I am having a problem working with NSString object.

My program created an object to store XY pairs.  The setters and getters work fine.  There is a print method which prints the datapoint to the console in "(x,y) format and this also works fine.

I wanted to add a method to return the point as a string with the form "(x,y)" in case it is going to be used for display elsewhere.

I thought it might have to do with needing to alloc / init the NSString being returned by toString method.  I did research the issue on stackoverflow but couldn't tell if I was doing it wrong.    [When not to alloc and init an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801156/when-not-to-alloc-and-init-an-nsstring)

Here are the header, interface and program files with the output.

**Header**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject

@property int x, y;

-(void) setX: (int) xVal andY: (int) yVal;
-(void) print;
- (NSString *) toString;
@end
```

**Implementation**

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation XYPoint

@synthesize x, y;

-(void) setX: (int) xVal andY: (int) yVal
{
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
}

-(void) print
{
NSLog(@" (%i,%i) ", x, y);
}

-(NSString *) toString
{

    NSString *stringXY = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" (%i,%i) ",self.x,self.y ];

    return stringXY;
}
@end
```

**Program**

```
#import "XYPoint.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {



        XYPoint *p1 = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

        [p1 setX:1 andY: 2];
        [p1 print];

        NSString *text = [p1 toString];
        NSLog(@"This is our data point %@",text);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the debugger and console.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not knowing what a user-set breakpoint is... there's literally nothing wrong with this code.  A user-set breakpoint is inhibited the program from continuing execution.

Comment: See that blue thing on line 33?  Right click it and click delete breakpoint and run your program again.

Comment: Wow!  Sorry.  AT least I only wasted 3 minutes of your time.  I spent an hour and a half not understanding that.  Thank you!